# Nonstandard algebraic geometry: Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

I have been trying to study the basics of algebraic geometry using nonstandard analysis and I can't wrap my head around this issue.

Let $^*\mathbb{C}$ be the extension of the complex numbers. Now fundamental theorem of algebra says that all polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ have solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. It also implies that a degree $n$ polynomial will have $n$ complex solutions. By transfer, this should also be true for polynomials in $^*\mathbb{C}[x]$. Now if you have a degree $n$ polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, then it has $n$ zeroes in $^*\mathbb{C}$ and these zeros must all be standard.

This also means that if $x \in {}^*\mathbb{C}$ is nonstandard, then $f(x) \neq 0$. However, I'm reading Nonstandard Generic Points by Guy Wallet, and he uses Nullstellensatz to show that for a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, $P$, there is a point $x \in {}^*\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x)=0$ iff $f \in P$.

This means there are standard polynomials that are zero on nonstandard numbers. Does this contradict the fundamental theorem of algebra? I appreciate any explanation. Thanks.

Comment: The statement "$x\in{}^*\mathbb{C}$" allows for $x$ to be standard (via the usual identification of $\mathbb{C}$ with a particular subfield of $^*\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Yes and the corresponding prime ideals for those points are the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. However not all prime ideals are maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: My point is that your conclusion "This means there are standard polynomials that are zero on nonstandard numbers" is unjustified.

Answer (score 5):

There's no contradiction here. The prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are the maximal ideals $(x - a), a \in \mathbb{C}$ and zero (the generic point). For the maximal ideals the desired point is $x = a$, which is standard. And for the zero ideal we can take any nonstandard point, since as you say a standard polynomial vanishes on a nonstandard point iff it's identically zero.